# ora-12519,no appropriate service handler found

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I get the `ORA-12519` *no appropriate service handler*-exception whenever I use infinite loops in my code. However, this code works perfectly in other systems.

This is my code

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        String dbHost = "localhost";
        String database = "scott";
        String dbUsername = "scott";
        String dbPassword = "scott";
        String smsReceiver = "";

        String dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";

        while (true) {
            ResultSet rs = null;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);

            try {
                Statement smnt = null;
                smnt = conn.createStatement();
                String sql = "select count(*) from ozekismsin";
                rs = smnt.executeQuery(sql);
                rs.next();

                int count = rs.getInt(1);
                if (count != 0) {
                    System.out.println("success");
                    sql = "select * from ozekismsin";
                    rs = smnt.executeQuery(sql);
                    rs.next();
                    String msg = rs.getString("msg");
                    // smsReceiver=rs.getString("sender");
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(msg, " ");
                    st.nextToken();
                    String source = st.nextToken();
                    st.nextToken();
                    String dest = st.nextToken();
                    System.out.println(source + " " + dest);
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
                    sql = "select id from new1 where name=?";
                    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, source);

                    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                    rs.next();

                    int s = rs.getInt("id");
                    System.out.println(source + " " + dest);
                    sql = "select id from new1 where name=?";
                    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, dest);
                    System.out.println(s);
                    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    rs.next();
                    int d = rs.getInt(1);
                    a = s;

                    test1 ob = new test1();
                    ob.dijkstra(s, d);

                    String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO "
                            + "ozekismsout (receiver,msg,status) "
                            + "VALUES " + "('" + smsReceiver + "','"
                            + message + "','send')";

                    if (smnt.executeUpdate(sqlInsert) != 0) {
                        System.out.println("OK");
                        System.out.println(message);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("ERROR");
                    }
                    sql = "delete from ozekismsin";
                    smnt.executeQuery(sql);
                    sql = "commit";
                    smnt.executeQuery(sql);
                } // end of if

                smnt.close();
                conn.close();
            } // end of try in while
            finally {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("exception caught");
                }
            } // end of finally
        } // end of while
    } // end of outer try
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} // end of main
```

This code works perfectly in other systems. But here it works only if I remove infinite loop.

Please any one help me.

Comment: Why are you only closing the result set once, and in the finally clause? You're reusing variables without cleaning them up, which may cause you to have more open cursors and connections than you think you have. Why are you repeatedly opening and closing the connection, and repeatedly redefining prepared statements? Do you get any other exceptions - are you relying on an exception to terminate the loop anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The error ORA-12519 may be caused by the current connection usage ( concurrernt sessions for example) is beyond the max amount allowed for the instance of Oracle.

Ask your DBA to tell you what connection limits are enforced - these settings are database specific, some values have defaults.  Ask.

As your code loops @AlexPoole noted that you are exhausting resources - you may be creating a slew of connections and not releasing them, for example.  I cannot tell for sure.  the 12519 error is a connection resource problem.  Period.  How you did it, I do not know.